# Are there nontrivial real functions of 2 real variables with gradient having constant euclidian norm on each level line?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $F$ be the class of locally Lipschitz continuous functions $z=f(x,y)$, from $\mathbb R \times\mathbb  R \to\mathbb R,$ such that the euclidean norm $|\ \mathrm{grad}\ f (x,y)\ |$ of its gradient vector is some function, call it $g,$ of its value, i.e.  $|\ grad\ f (x,y)\ | = g(\ f(x, y)\ )\ a.e..$
Let $T$ be the subclass of those functions $f$ in $F$ which are a constant $c$ times the distance to some nonempty set, so that $|\ \mathrm{grad}\ f\ | = |\ c\ |\ a.e..$
I call $T$ the class of trivial functions in $F$.
Question: are there nontrivial functions in $F$ ? That is, $F = T$ ?
If yes, how does one prove it ?
If not, can you give me a specific example of a nontrivial function ?
Otherwise, how do you show that $F$ is larger than $T$ ?
Or, more generally, what is the general form of functions in the class $F$ ?

Comment: The distance to a nonempty set doesn't have continuous partial derivatives. $(x,y) \mapsto ax+by$ does.

Comment: previous comment gives a non-trivial function, according to your definition. On the other hand distance to say two points is not differentiable, and distance to a non-empty set is 0 on this set, in particular if this set is open, then grad distance is also 0 on this set (but not outside this set).

Comment: We probably want to consider functions on open sets $U\subset\mathbb R^2$ here.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82227/solutions-to-the-eikonal-equation

Comment: Please notice that my first version was incorrectly stated. Please do read my new version, since your comments do not seem helpful for the new (correct) formulation. This one is what I had in mind from the beginning, but was distracted in writing my first version. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in $F$ and $T$ are, at least around a level set where the gradient is nontrivial, the same up to "reparametrizations preserving level sets." To see this, assume that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is in $F$, that $0$ is a nontrivial level set of $f$, and that $g > 0$ in a neighborhood of $0$. If we take a function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $h(0) = 0$ and $h'(z) = \frac{1}{g(z)}$ then the function $\tilde{f}(x) = h(f(x))$ has the same level sets of $f$, and furthermore
$$|\nabla\tilde{f}| = h'(f)|\nabla f| = 1,$$
so $\tilde{f}$ is the signed distance from its $0$ level set nearby this set. Heuristically, we "adjusted the heights of horizontal slices of $f$" so that it becomes the distance function.

As a simple example, take the simple example $f(x) = |x|^2$. Since $|\nabla f| = 2|x| = 2\sqrt{f}$ we have that $f \in F$. Then taking $h(z) = \sqrt{z}$ we transform this function to $|x|$, the distance from $0$. If we have any increasing radial function we can do the same. More generally, one can view the above discussion as saying that any $f \in F$ can, around "nondegenerate level sets," be written as some reparametrization of the distance function from this level set.