# Do geodesics avoid regions where the curvature diverges?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, geodesics

Let $(M^2,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, with manifold boundary $\partial M$. We assume that the metric degenerates at the boundary, in the sense that the (Gauss) curvature diverges like $K \to +\infty$ as one approaches it.

**Question.** Is it true that 'nearly all' geodesics avoid the boundary? Perhaps those going to the boundary are meagre in some sense?

- In general, it seems intuitively reasonable that 'most' geodesics would avoid regions where the curvature is 'large and positive'. (This is of course a bit vague—I was unable to come up with a precise formulation.)
- The question is motivated by a comment made in passing by Robert Bryant in his answer to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398359/when-does-the-eikonal-equation-lvert-du-rvert2-f-admit-a-local-solution), where he discussed the geodesics of a very specific metric.

Comment: the thing that comes to mind  is the Clairaut relation for surfaces of revolution  such as $z = x^2 + y^2,$ with positive curvature near the origin. Every geodesic that does not pass through the origin (not a meridean) achieves a minimum distance from it, so every non-meridean geodesic can be produced by specifying a point where it is parallel to the $xy$ plane. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_relation_(differential_geometry)

Comment: @WillJagy Sure, Clairaut's relation is essentially the heuristic which suggested to me that 'most' geodesics ought to avoid regions where the curvature is 'large'. However, I am not sure it gives much more here, as I don't want to impose rotational symmetry.

Comment: I had never thought about this before, but am having trouble imagining  a smooth 2D riemannian manifold M with boundary such that its gaussian curvature K(p) → ∞ as p → ∂M.  Is that even possible?

Comment: Now that I've thought about it, it seems possible (but very counterintuitive to me):

Answer (score 2):

It seems to fail for
$(y^2+z^2-1)^2=x^3$,
$x\geqslant 0.$